# Setting ORDER BY and LIMIT clause on JPA Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm very, very new to Hibernate and JPA. I want to be able to apply ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses to a Hibernate(?) query, but am coming up empty. **NOTE: I inherited this code.**

Here is the current code:

```
public SomeCoolResponse getSomeCoolResponse(String myId) {
    String queryString = "select aThing from AWholeBunchOfThings aThing " +
    "join aThing.thisOtherThing oThing join oThing.StillAnotherThing saThing " + 
    "where saThing.subthing.id = :id";

    Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
    q.setParameter("id", myId);

    List<MyThings> list = q.getResultList();

    if(list.size() > 0) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Instead of getting an entire list and then just returning the first result (which is the only one we need), I'd like to be able to apply a `LIMIT 0,1` clause so that the query will be faster. Also, the query needs to be sorted descending on `aThing.created` which is a UNIX timestamp integer.

I've tried altering `queryString` like this:

```
String queryString = "select aThing from AWholeBunchOfThings aThing " +
    "join aThing.thisOtherThing oThing join oThing.StillAnotherThing saThing " + 
    "where saThing.subthing.id = :id ORDER BY aThing.created LIMIT 0,1";
```

But Hibernate still returns the entire set.

I've looked at using the JPA CriteriaBuilder API, but it hurt my brain.

I'm a total n00b when it comes to this, and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: JPQL is not SQL; database specifics like `limit` are not supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need

```
q.setMaxResults(1);
```

See also the accepted answer here.

[How do you do a limit query in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql)

As to the "order by" clause you may include it in the `queryString`.

Comment: Then should I be able to use `q.getSingleResult()`?

Comment: @daniel0mullins You mean uniqueResult()? Just call setMaxResults and your query will return at most one record. If you look at the generated SQL I think it will contain the LIMIT clause so it's exactly what you needed.

Comment: @daniel0mullins OK, I thought we were talking org.hibernate.Query.

Comment: like I said - total n00b

Comment: @daniel0mullins Then look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655870/jpa-2-criteriaquery-using-a-limit

Comment: @daniel0mullins Hm, seems there's such a method on javax.persistence.Query http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29. So I guess my original answer applies to javax.persistence.Query too.

Comment: I think we're using Java 7(?)...regardless - your suggestion worked! Sped up my query by about 1000% down to 5s from 50s. Thanks!

Comment: Does the database return an entire list which is then limited by the jpql engine or does the jpql engine create a native sql query with limit clause?

Answer (score 2):

The JPQL equivalent to LIMIT start,max is:

`setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`:

```
q.setFirstResult(start); 
q.setMaxResults(limit);
```